# Switch button value with enum mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, enums

I already have my script working, but I want it to be simpler.

There are 2 buttons which will update the the column `crap` to `yes` and the other one to `no`. This is my current script, but I want it to be merged together and exist of only 1 button:

```
if(isset($_POST['nocrap'])){
    $query = "UPDATE users SET yescrap = 'nee' WHERE username = '$log_username'";
    $nocrap = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
    if($nocrap){
        $succes = '<font color="red">Je bent nu uit de queue!</font>';
    } else
    {
        $error = '<font color="red">Er is iets mis gegaan!</font>';
    }
}
```

```
if(isset($_POST['yescrap'])){
    $query = "UPDATE users SET yescrap = 'ja' WHERE username = '$log_username'";
    $yescrap = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
    if($yescrap){
        $succes = '<font color="green">Je zit nu in de queue!</font>';
    } else
    {
        $succes = '<font color="red">Er is iets mis gegaan!</font>';
    }
}
```

Also, when `yescrap` value is `ja`, I want the button to display:

```
$button = '<input type="submit" name="nocrap" value="nocrap" />';
else 
$button = '<input type="submit" name="yescrap" value="yescrap" />';
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP Code** (Not been tested)

```
if (isset($_POST['crap']) && ($_POST['crap'] == "yes" || $_POST['crap'] == "no"))
    $crapValue = "nee";
    $crapSuccess = "Je bent nu uit de queue!";
    if ($_POST['crap'] == "yes") {
        $crapValue = "ja";
        $crapSuccess = "Je zit nu in de queue!";
    }

    $query = "UPDATE users SET yescrap = '$crapValue' WHERE username = '$log_username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
    $succes = '<font color="red">Er is iets mis gegaan!</font>';
    if($result){
        $succes = '<font color="green">$crapSuccess</font>';
    }
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
$button = '<input type="submit" name="crap" value="yes" />';
else
$button = '<input type="submit" name="crap" value="no" />';
```

**Notice:** Not using a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) protection is highly unsafe and dangerous.

Comment: i'm sorry but i can't figure it out can you help me abit more please ? thanks for your response btw!

Comment: @Darren, Instead of two different buttons, I've created 2 buttons with the same name(Crap) but with different values(Yes and No). And on the server side, I'm checking if the "Crap" is set and if so, if it is "Yes"/"No" if it is "Yes" i'm setting the SQL `yescrap` column as "ja" otherwise "nee". Understandable ?